# KSH | `-n` option inside an if statement

Tags: ksh

I was checking a korn shell script and I stumbled upon this:

```
if [[ -n `echo "This is an example." | grep -E "example"` ]]; then
  # Do something.
fi
```

Can someone tell me what the `-n` is doing?

Comment: It tests if the argument (which in this case is the output of the command inside the backticks) has non-zero length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting to check this [article](https://www.qenesis.com/training/shell_programming/kshCheatsheet.pdf):

```
 [[ -n "string" ]] true if length of string is greater than zero
```

Similar to

```
if [[ `echo "This is an example." | grep -Ec "example"` -gt 0 ]]; then
  # Do something.
fi
```

Also better practice for `if` statements:

```
if [[ -n $(echo "This is an example." | grep -E "example") ]]; then
  # Do something.
fi
```

Comment: or when you can't recall which flag means what ... `[[ $(echo "This is an example." | grep -E "example") != '' ]]`